# The initial value of an input in PHP

Tags: php

Here is a quick question:
the code like this

`<input type="hidden" name="HDN_FormClicked" value="WasClicked" />`

```
if (strlen($_POST["HDN_FormClicked"]) > 0){
  echo "You have clicked the button";
}
```

Does if check the input value every time? So why is the input  not greater than 0 at the first time? Is it some initial setting?

Thanks for help:).

Comment: please include the full form so we can see where it's posting to. My guess is you are posting to itself rather than a different page, hence on page load you don't have a value.
you can shorten your code also like this: `if($_POST['HDN_FormClicked'])`. If `HDN_FormClicked` has a value, the statement will be `true` else it will be `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This value will only (and always) be set when you `POST` your form, not first time when you just load your page without form submit. You could modify it a little to avoid that confusion

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
if (strlen($_POST["HDN_FormClicked"]) > 0){
  echo "You have clicked the button";
}
}
else
{
echo "Form was not submitted this time";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

bad solution, but the answer to your question is: because form values not yet sent to server. So after first send, you will have it filled. by just showing the input, data are not sent.

Comment: Got it, so the value should be null at the first time? Could you give me some hints that how to this thing right since you say it is a bad solution? Thank you

Comment: firstly, you really need strlen there? so check if value is set before making any calculations with if (isset($_POST["HDN_FormClicked"])) then you will not get any warnings and it will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Pluto, maybe I'm missing something here or perhaps there might be a slight misunderstanding on how a form communicates with PHP.

PHP is not aware of the form data you're displaying on the page, all it knows is it's outputting text. When you perform a form submission, that's when PHP recognizes that form data has been passed to it.

Envision we have page with the following code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['HDN_FormClicked']) {
  print 'You have clicked the button';
} else {
  print 'Form was not submitted this time';
}
?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="HDN_FormClicked" value="1" />
  <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

By default, the text above the form will display "Form was not submitted this time".

The moment you press the "Click" button, the form will post to the script, PHP will detect that form elements have been passed, and will print "You have clicked the button".